# ASP .NET VB Get Posted File

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have inherited an old ASP/VB Web Application project, and am trying to get it running on my computer (Win 7, VS Web Express 2012), but have never done any ASP or VB before.

I have an `Upload2.aspx` file and an `Upload2.aspx.vb` file.

`Upload2.aspx` looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Upload2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Upload2" %>
...
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuData" runat="server" />
```

`Upload2.aspx.vb` looks like this:

```
Partial Class Upload2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub manageUpload()
        Dim pf As HttpPostedFile = fuData.PostedFile
...
```

For some reason, it is giving me an error at fuData:
`'fuData' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`

Shouldn't it automatically be able to access the variable from the id on the aspx page?

Comment: could you try to look at Upload2.aspx.designer.vb, it a generated file

Comment: There is no designer file...